# How do i add additional text to a joomla contact page

Tags: php, joomla

This is my first time using joomla.  I don't know if I'm using the concept of a Contact in the wrong way, but I have a Contact Us menu that I've created and I've added the contact details in.  I'm looking to add a sentence or two of text above the contact details & the e-mail contact form.  There doesn't seem to be a way of doing this via the administration page. Am I doing the right thing?  What do I need to do if I want this?

Comment: what about my answer? didn't it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want it above the contact details you have to work with a layout-override. There is no way to do this through the admin backend. In Joomla 1.0 it was only possible with a hack, now in Joomla 1.5 there is the possibility of layout override.

[This article](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) shows how it's done.

If you want to see it live, install the beez template, which has overrides for nearly all core components of Joomla. So you can check how beez does it and then do something similar with your own template.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly above the contact information but above the e-mail form you can use the "Miscellaneous Info" field to put any extra Data.

Comment: It could work if it was possible to re-shuffle the order the fields are displayed.  I'll look into that

Answer (score 0):

You can try making your own custom contact form. 
You must make the Custom HTML Contact Form and while using sendmail() function of PHP. You will find many PHP based contact forms available online.
Use 'Jumi' Plugin to link the send button with the php code.
Everything works perfectly like it should. I used it to make one of my contact forms.

Comment: C2h: Do you have much experience with the Jumi plugin?  I am trying to "link" to a Jumi call using an href but having problems, do you know if this is possible?